# Redundancy due to npm install while modules exist globally?

Tags: node.js, npm-install, node-modules

I just cloned a project and did `npm install`... only to realise that although certain modules were already globally installed, they were still locally installed!? Is this normal? If so, isn't this causing redundant installation? Is there an official way to counter this?

Comment: `npm` first search the `module` in locally if it does not exist then it search globally, where all the packages are installed and the location can vary  depends on `OS`. Then it should not be affected.